# Multi steps creation process in backpack-for-laravel create operation

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I am using `backpack-for-laravel` `V4` installed on `laravel 6.1.0` and I want when I create a new entity (inside `CreateOperation`) multi steps creation wizard as follow:

- View 1: which displays a form to upload an excel file
- Controller action: do the upload process using `laravel-excel`
- View 2: a form to match the database table fields with the excel file header row
- Controller action: create models and save them as many their are as the rows

I did all the above steps in a normal frontend form and save the result correctly in the database. I just need hints or tips how to accomplish the same in `backpack-for-laravel` so the process will be in the crud panel.

Please advice,

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that by creating a custom operation with multiple actions as the number of required steps before storing the data to the database.

- [Creating Custom Operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation)

Comment: any suggestion on the procedure?